# Master Method - Recurrence relation with two Ts

Tags: algorithm, master-theorem

I am taking a data structures and algorithms course (which has been tough). We learned about the master method to solve basic recurrence relations when they are in the form aT(n/b)+f(n). Now we have learned about the linear time selection algorithm which has a relation that is not in this form and I am being asked to find its worse case running time is asymptotic notation.

I have found the the recurrence relation as:

[image: formula1]

It seems to me that the Master Method does not account for this - I may very well be wrong. If it doesn't, then how do you find the worse case running time?

Comment: Are you sure about the recurrence? Is it really something close to `T(n)<T(0.01*n)+T(0.75*n+100)+O(n)`?

Comment: @LutzL The given problem is asking if we create sub groups of size 101. Normally the linear time selection algorithm is using groupings that are small like 3, 5 or 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The master theorem doesn't apply, but it's not too hard to prove a tight bound for this recurrence directly.

You know you can't do better than **O(n)**, because that term is already in the recurrence.  You have been told that it's a linear time algorithm and with some experience you would guess that from the fact that the total size of the subproblems is smaller than n by some factor, so it is a good bet that you can do **O(n)**.

What remains is to prove it.

You can prove this pretty easily by induction.  Let C be a (large) constant such that:

**T(n) <= T(n/101 + 1) + T(151n/202 + 101) + C(n+1)/202**, for all **n**,  (eq 1), and

**T(n) <= C(n+1)**, for all **n < 1000**  (eq 2)

For any **n >= 1000**, if (eq 2) holds for all smaller **n**, then we have

**T(n) <= T(n/101 + 1) + T(151n/202 + 101) + C(n+1)/202**  (eq 1)

**T(n) <= C(n+202)/101 + C(151n+20604)/202 + C(n+1)/202** (subst eq 2)

**T(n) <= C(2n+404)/202 + C(151n+20604)/202 + C(n+1)/202**

**T(n) <= C(156n+20604)/202**

**T(n) <= C(0.78n + 102) <= C(n - 0.22n + 102) <= C(n - 220 + 102)**  (because n>=1000)

**T(n) <= C(n+1)**

So, if we choose **C** as above, then the fact that (eq 2) holds for **n < 1000** implies that it holds for all **n**, and **T(n) is in O(n)**

Comment: That makes sense. I guess I assumed that the recurrence relation meant this had to be solved with the master method. Thanks for the help.